# Creating Dataflow Templates for use in multiple GCP projects

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm looking to set up a proper deployment pipeline for our Dataflow jobs, allowing Continuous Delivery and QA testing of specific versions of our jobs.

In order to do this I'm looking to "build" the jobs into artifacts that can be referenced and executed in different places. I've been looking into Dataflow Templates in order to do this, but it seems like a template has to be built for a specific GCP project, meaning that I can't share the artifacts between my staging and production projects.

Is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do? What do people generally do in order to enforce a predictable deployment pipeline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a job based on a template you can override the project. Here is an example in Go.

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "golang.org/x/oauth2/google"
    "google.golang.org/api/dataflow/v1b3"
)

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    projectID := "PROJECT"
    bucket := "gs://BUCKET/"
    input := "gs://dataflow-samples/shakespeare/kinglear.txt"
    output := bucket + "shakespeare"
    temp := bucket + "temp"
    template := "gs://dataflow-templates/wordcount/template_file"

    client, err := google.DefaultClient(ctx, "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform")

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    dataflowService, err := dataflow.New(client)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    templateService := dataflow.NewProjectsTemplatesService(dataflowService)


    mapP := map[string]string{"inputFile": input, "output": output}

    env := dataflow.RuntimeEnvironment{TempLocation: temp}
    r := dataflow.CreateJobFromTemplateRequest{GcsPath: template, Parameters: mapP, Environment: &env}

    resp, err := templateService.Create(projectID, &r).Do()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("Job URL: https://console.cloud.google.com/dataflow/job/%s?project=%s\n", resp.Id, resp.ProjectId)
}
```

Comment: My problem is that the job seems to be configured to use resources in the project it was created in rather than the project it's running in – and I get permission errors as a result.

Comment: Specifically, the `temp-location` needs to be writable by the job, but it's set statically at job creation time.

Comment: Also, a lot of stuff has to be defined statically, e.g. pubsub subscriptions. I need a different set of subscriptions for each project I'm running the job in.

Comment: The example overwrites the temp location (see "env").For PubSub, I see ValueProviders in Read -- so you should be able to pass topic and subscription at runtime.